# How to display attached properties in Property Browser of blend for silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, design-time

I created couple of custom controls and their childresn correctly shows the attached properties in Property Browser for WPF, but in silverlight none of the attached properties appear in Property Brower.

How to add design time support for attached properties in silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there might be some attributes to work with to make custom properties appear in the designer:
http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2008/01/17/showing-attached-properties-in-the-cider-wpf-designer.aspx

I have not tried it though, not sure if it will work with Silverlight.

Comment: I did everything this article said, in VS 2010, everything appears fine, but Expression 3 doesnt show up anything yet, will wait for expression 4.

Answer (score 0):

Henrik's definitely works for WPF in VS2015/Blend.  Just for reference, I'm adding some of the info from the linked article because so many times links to blogs die after a number of years.

> AttachedPropertyBrowsableWhenAttributePresentAttribute
>
> This attribute allows you to specify that your attached property show
>   up in the Property Browser when the selected item has a given
>   attribute applied to it.  If the attribute has a default value, that
>   value also has to be different from the default value.
>
> In the example above that passes in “MyCustomAttribute” as the
>   attribute to look for, when CustomLabel below is selected in the
>   designer, the Property Browser will show the ShowWhenCustomAttribute
>   attached property however it will not when
>   CustomLabelNoCustomAttribute is selected:

```
[MyCustomAttribute]
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
}

public class CustomLabelNoCustomAttribute : Label
{
}
```

AttachedPropertyBrowsableForChildrenAttribute

This attribute indicates that the attached property should be available for the children of the given control.  There are two main flavors for this attribute.  One that includes descendants and one that does not. As you might expect including descendants refers to including all children or simply the direct children of the control.

```
[AttachedPropertyBrowsableForChildrenAttribute(IncludeDescendants=true)]
public static int GetShowForChildrenDeep(UIElement element)
{
    return (int)element.GetValue(ShowForChildrenDeepProperty);
}
```

AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType

This attribute allows you to specify that your attached property show up when a given type or types derived from that type are selected in the designer.  The following sample would make your attached property show up when any Grid, derived Grid, Button or derived Button is selected.

```
[AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(Grid))]
[AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(Button))]
public static int GetShowForTypes(UIElement element)
{
    return (int)element.GetValue(ShowForTypesProperty);
}
```

And here are the MSDN doc links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.attachedpropertybrowsableforchildrenattribute(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.attachedpropertybrowsablefortypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.attachedpropertybrowsablewhenattributepresentattribute(v=vs.110).aspx